# Ssh access to a server with internet access but no public IP address

Tags: ssh, networking, remote, connectivity

I have an `ssh` server running Kubuntu 22.04 behind a router providing internet connection, but without a public IP (this is the policy of the ISP). So, the server can access the internet, but any port mapping between the router and the `ssh` server is useless, so the server is not directly accessible from the internet.

I would like instead to be able to access the server via `ssh` from another internet host. If possible, I would like to do this without spending money.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

As correctly guessed in the comments, the `ssh` server is behind a CGNAT, so its router has no public IP address and is not reachable.

Comment: I'm certain that the router has a public IP address, but maybe not a _static_ public IP address. What you are asking about is then probably about how to use some sort of dynamic DNS service, like DuckDNS or similar?

Comment: I guess this is CG-NAT? You'll need a reverse tunnel setup. Have a local client create a persistent connection to the internet host, and use that to connect back into LAN. Consider `ssh` for this or `wireguard`

Comment: see https://superuser.com/q/1258093/992527

Comment: Could this help ?  
https://superuser.com/questions/1017179/access-my-local-network-from-internet-without-public-ip

Comment: @Kusalananda it's increasingly common for domestic Internet service to be provisioned through CG-NAT. Each customer has an external IP address from (say) 10.0.0.0/8, and they are all aggregated by the ISP to one of a small number of public routable IP addresses. Your mobile phone provider almost certainly does this already. Net effect is that no matter what someone tries, it's not possible for someone not a customer of that ISP to connect directly to the WAN port of their router

Comment: Ah! Thanks @roaima! I learnt something new today.

Comment: IPv6 might be an answer, if it just so happens you have a public v6 address along with that CGNAT:ed v4 address. (that's what my cellphone seems to have right now)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/).  You install this on the server and the client from where you wish to connect.

It *JUST WORKS*. And, there is a free version for personal use. Probably the best mesh VPN solution (based on wireguard) out there.

For more info, see https://tailscale.com/blog/how-tailscale-works/